# bundler not recognizing platform? Could not find gem

Tags: jruby, bundler, neo4j

I'm using jruby 1.7.2 and setting up a new rails app.  Bundler appears unable to find the necessary (java/jruby based gems) to use:

```
> bundle
Could not find gem 'neo4j-core (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

If I specify the path, I get this:

```
> bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Could not find gem 'neo4j-core (>= 0) ruby' in source at ./vendor/gems/neo4j-core.
Source contains 'neo4j-core' at: 2.0.1
```

Perhaps bundler is getting confused about its platoform -- why would it be tacking the word `ruby` on the end there?  I ran `ruby -e "puts RUBY_PLATFORM"`, which gave me: `java`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved by deleting Gemfile.lock: https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/2043

Comment: Your Gemfile.lock was probably generated for ruby and when you switched to jruby the gem (in ruby) just wasn't there. When you deleted the Gemfile.lock, the dependencies were re-generated for jruby and woohoo. Had the same issue and took me a while to figure it out. Thanks for a good tip!